# Check whether the input is digit or not in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, digit

I am currently reading this book: [The C Programming Language - By Kernighan and Ritchie (second Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and one of the examples I am having trouble understanding how to check whether the input is digit or not. The example is on Page 22, explaining under the array chapter.

Below is the example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 /* count digits, white space, others */

 main()
 {
   int c, i, nwhite, nother;
   int ndigit[10];

   nwhite = nother = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
       ndigit[i] = 0;
   }

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   {
     if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     {
         ++ndigit[c-'0'];
     }
     else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
     {
         ++nwhite;
     }
     else
     {
         ++nother;
     }

   printf("digits =");

   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
   }

   printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",nwhite, nother);
 }
```

For this example, what confused me is that the author mentioned that the line `++ndigit[c-'0']` checks whether the input character in c is a digit or not.  However, I believe that only the if statement `( if (c>= '0' && c<= '9') )` is necessary, and it will check if c is digit or not. Plus, I do not understand why `[c-'0']` will check the input(c) is digit or not while the input variable (c) is subtracted from the string-casting ('0').

Any suggestions/explanations would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Either you misread K&R or they have an error. The way I read the code is that if c is a digit, increment the corresponding value of ndigit. So for example if c == '7', then c-'0' = '7'-'0' = 7 (because the character coding of digits is contiguous), and hence the code will increment digit[7].

Comment: Michael L, put that as an answer. @jimmcnamara point of this exercise is to write isdigit function by your self.

Comment: If you are satisfied then please mark one the answers as accepted

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement checks whether the character is a digit, and the `++ndigit[c-'0']` statement updates the count for that digit. When `c` is a character between `'0'` and `'9'`, then `c-'0'` is a number between `0` and `9`.  To put it another way, the ASCII value for `'0'` is 48 decimal, `'1'` is 49, `'2'` is 50, etc. So `c-'0'` is the same as `c-48`, and converts `48,49,50,...` to `0,1,2...`

One way to improve your understanding is to add a `printf` to the code, e.g. replace

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

with

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
{
    ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    printf( "is digit '%c'   ASCII=%d   array_index=%d\n", c, c, c-'0' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to explain with an example

suppose the input is abc12323

So the frequency of 1=1

frequency of 2=2

frequency of 3=2

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') //checks whether c is a  digit  
      ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

Now if you do  printf("%d",c) then you will get the ascii value of the

character

for c='0' the ascii value will be 48,c='1' ascii value will be 49 and it goes

till 57 for c='9'.

In your program you are keeping a frequency of the digits in the input so you need to update the index of the digit in the array every time you get it

if you do ndigit[c]++ then it will update ndigit[48] for c='0',ndigit[49] for c='1'

So either you can do ndigit[c-'0']++ as ascii value of '0'=48 in decimal

or you can simply do ndigit[c-48]++ so for c='0' ndigit[0] is updated,c=1'

ndigit[1] is updated

you can check the re factored code here http://ideone.com/nWZxL1

Hope it helps you,Happy Coding